# What are a few good ways to load images dynamically?

Tags: c#, javascript, loading

I have a main home page. And I want to do what what a lot of sites are currently doing where they dynamically show a few large images dynamically. Specifically, I have 5 images that are 900px by 400px that I want to show - I can do it with a Javascript setInterval etc. - but I want to know how I can add some fade effects too - I'm coding in c#, but the only elegant way I can think to do it is with javascript - if anyone can give me a link to a tutorial or paste a code snippet of the way they like to do it, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you couldn't use `C#` to do it unless you are talking about silverlight.

Comment: Since he talked of javascript, i suggested him to use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding in C# will not get you fade effects, you will need Javascript. You can use C# to load the first instance of the image of course, but anything with effects or timers need to be in Javascript or jQuery. Most sites will actually use a jQuery plugin for this main fade in/fade out slideshow feature. There are plenty of slider plugins out there that will be good for you.

Here's a little something that could get you going, if you feel you want to build your own.

```
<img src="img0.jpg">
<img src="img1.jpg">
<img src="img2.jpg">
<img src="img3.jpg">

$(function() {

    var i = 0;

    // Four-second interval
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#img").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "img" + i++ % 4 + ".jpg");
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 4000);
}
```

Every 4 seconds it iterates through the images 1 to 4, fading in and out.

Alternatively, you can just download a pre-built jQuery slider plugin, like one of the following:

- http://nivo.dev7studios.com/
- http://slidesjs.com/
- http://snook.ca/technical/fade/fade.html
- http://wowslider.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll just go with your jQuery since I wanted to start to incorporate jQuery anyway.

Comment: @Mikey: Glad I could assist. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a jQuery image carousal.

Putting up some of the best links in here.

1) http://wowslider.com/demo.html : Awesome piece, can be integrated quite well.
2) http://www.jcoverflip.com/ 
3) http://galleria.io/ : Phenomenal

You may also have a look at [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) so that you can better implement one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

BXSlider is a great lightweight simple to use jquery slider.

See http://bxslider.com.

Features

- Horizontal, vertical, and fade transitions
- Display and move multiple slides at once (carousel)
- Prev / next, pager, auto controls
- Easing transitions
- Random start
- Ticker mode
- Before, after, first, last, next, prev callback functions
- Optional styling included
- Tons of options

Comment: I have tried various sliders and found this one to be a lot simpler/easier to implement. (most seem to come with lots of headache)